# Django render and redirect URL

Tags: python, django, redirect

Hello i'm a newbie to Django, i'm currently having problem figure out how to  redirect and return value

I have a url with 2 parameters that are **month** and **year** . After clicking on it , it should redirect to page with url like so "list-working-sessions/year/month" with year and month parameters base on the action.

urls.py

```
url(r'^list-working-sessions/(?P<year>\w+?)/(?P<month>\w+?)/$', 
        views.list_working_sessions, 
        name='list_working_sessions')
```

base.html

```
           <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li id="list-daily-task">
              <a href="{% url 'list_working_sessions' %}">
                <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>List Working Session</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

The page have a table and a form to search by month and year:

list_working_sessions.html

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
        <center>
            <h3 class="box-title">List Working Sessions</h3>
        </center>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-header -->
    <div class="box-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="/list-working-sessions" method="GET">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="table-responsive">  
                <table class="table table-borderless" id="dynamic_field">
                    <tr>
                    <th style="width:20%; border-top:none">Month</th>
                    <th style="width:20%; border-top:none">Year</th>
                    <th style="width:20%; border-top:none"></th>
                    <th style="border-top:none"></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>  
                    <td style="border-top:none">
                        <select name="month" class="form-control" id="month" required>
                        <option value="1" selected>1</option>
                        <option value="2" selected>2</option>
                        <option value="3" selected>3</option>
                        <option value="4" selected>4</option>
                        <option value="5" selected>5</option>
                        <option value="6" selected>6</option>
                        <option value="7" selected>7</option>
                        <option value="8" selected>8</option>
                        <option value="9" selected>9</option>
                        <option value="10" selected>10</option>
                        <option value="11" selected>11</option>
                        <option value="12" selected>12</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-top:none">
                        <select name="year" class="form-control" id="year" required>
                        <option value="2019" selected>2019</option>
                        <option value="2020" selected>2020</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-top:none"><button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>  
                </div>  
        </form>
        <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Working Sessions</th>
                    <th>Duration</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for lws in working_session_list|dictsortreversed:"date"%}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{lws.date}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            {% for lgbd in lws.list_group_by_date %}
                                <ul>
                                    {% for item in lgbd.items %}
                                        <li>{{item.start.time}} - {{item.end.time|default:"Not ended yet" }}</li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{lws.sum_duration}} minutes
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            </tfoot>

        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
```

If the link is clicked from base.html then it will return list_working_sessions.html page with table value(working session objects) from the current month and year and the url have current month and year parameter. If the link is the GET request from the form then it will return the page with table values from the search month and year and the url also include that parameter

I wrote the following view so it handle all in 1 function but i'm having problem figure out how to redirect and return values from the function and also changing url parameter. I'm used to doing POST form request but never do redirect with GET form request before

views.py:

```
def list_working_sessions(request):
    flag_date = []
    working_session_list = []

    if request.method == 'GET':
        month = int(request.GET.get('month'))
        year = int(request.GET.get('year'))
        daily_working_sessions = WorkingSession.objects.filter(device__employee_id=request.user,start__month=month,start__year=year).order_by('-start')
    else:
        month = datetime.today().month
        year = datetime.today().year
        daily_working_sessions = WorkingSession.objects.filter(device__employee_id=request.user).order_by('-start')

    for item in daily_working_sessions:
        if item.start.date() not in flag_date:
            flag_date.append(item.start.date())
            list_group_by_date = []
            group_by_date = daily_working_sessions.filter(start__date=item.start.date())
            list_group_by_date.append({
                "items": group_by_date
            })

            sum_duration = 0

            for item in group_by_date:
                sum_duration += item.get_duration

            working_session_list.append({
                "date": str(item.start.date()),
                "list_group_by_date": list_group_by_date,
                "sum_duration": sum_duration
            })
    num_days = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
    days = [date(year, month, day) for day in range(1, num_days+1)]
    for day in days:
        if day not in flag_date:
            working_session_list.append({
                "date": day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                "list_group_by_date": '',
                "sum_duration": '0'
            })
    return render(request, 'pages/list_working_sessions.html', {
        'working_session_list': working_session_list,
        'state': 'list-working-sessions'
    })
    url = reverse('list_working_sessions', kwargs={'year': year, 'month': month})
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

**EDIT**:
i changed base.html to

```
{% now "Y" as YEAR %}
{% now "m" as MONTH %}
<a href="{% url 'list_working_sessions' year=YEAR month=MONTH %}">
```

and the error gone but when i click on the url from base.html got this

> TypeError at /list-working-sessions/2019/07/ list_working_sessions()
>   got an unexpected keyword argument 'year'

**EDIT 2**:
i changed my view function to :

```
def list_working_sessions(request, month, year):
    flag_date = []
    working_session_list = []
    month = int(month)
    year = int(year)

    daily_working_sessions = WorkingSession.objects.filter(device__employee_id=request.user,start__month=month,start__year=year).order_by('-start')
```

and the URL from base.html return the right redirect URL '/list-working-sessions/2019/7/' and value in table but when i search with the form the URL is different

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8888/list_working_sessions_get?month=8&year=2019
```

can't seem to get month and year from this URL to my view function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the view to pass year and month arguments:

```
def list_working_sessions(request, year, month):
    flag_date = []
    working_session_list = []

    if request.method == 'GET':
        # removed request.GET.get(...) because year and month arguments coming direct in from url and view arguments
        daily_working_sessions = WorkingSession.objects.filter(device__employee_id=request.user,start__month=month,start__year=year).order_by('-start')
    else:
        month = datetime.today().month
        year = datetime.today().year
```

---

**Update** I think you can try like this:

```
# url
url(r'^list-working-sessions/', 
    views.list_working_sessions, 
    name='list_working_sessions')

# view(same as your question)
def list_working_sessions(request):
    flag_date = []
    working_session_list = []

    if request.method == 'GET':
        month = int(request.GET.get('month'))
        year = int(request.GET.get('year'))
    # rest of the code
    url = '{}?year={}&month={}'.format(reverse('list_working_sessions'), year, month)

# template:
{% now "Y" as YEAR %}
{% now "m" as MONTH %}
<a href="{% url 'list_working_sessions' %}?year={{ YEAR }}&month={{ MONTH }}">
```

---

**Update2** I think you can try like this:

```
# url
url(r'^list-working-sessions/', 
    views.list_working_sessions, 
    name='list_working_sessions'),
url(r'^list-working-sessions/(?P<year>\w+?)/(?P<month>\w+?)/$', 
    views.list_working_sessions, 
    name='list_working_sessions_updated')

# view
def list_working_sessions(request, year=None, month=None):
    flag_date = []
    working_session_list = []
    redirect = False
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if not month:
            month = int(request.GET.get('month'))
            redirect = True
        if not year:
            year = int(request.GET.get('year'))
            redirect = True
    # other codes
    if not redirect:
         return render(...)
    else:
         url = reverse('list_working_sessions_updated', kwargs={'year': year, 'month': month})
         return HttpResponseRedirect(url)


# template:
{% now "Y" as YEAR %}
{% now "m" as MONTH %}
<a href="{% url 'list_working_sessions_updated' year=YEAR month=MONTH %}">
```

Comment: i changed in the edit of the question and it worked and got the default month and year url when click on the url in base.html but when i try to search with the form GET i get the following url Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8888/list_working_sessions_get?month=8&year=2019 it seems like i can't get the parameter from form GET url in my view

Comment: No, you need to match the url signature. But you can try like this update section of the answer

Comment: i got TypeError at /list-working-sessions/
list_working_sessions() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'month' and 'year'  in base.html url, it  can't get the month and year value ?

Comment: oh nice it worked but the url is now '/list-working-sessions/?month=8&year=2019' which is not the redirect url i wrote in my view the format should be '/list-working-sessions/2019/8' is there anyway to change to it ? i will accept the answer because it helped my code flow work :))

Comment: hmm it doesn't change my url, seems like the url = '{}?month={}&year={}'.format(reverse('list_working_session'), month, year)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url) part doesn't even used

Comment: Ah, I missed that. There is a `return` before you are using reverse. You need to remove or do what it is necessary for this view :)

Comment: but redirect doesn't support return value , so i can't render for the view and just change the url (keep the same page) with redirect ? i need working_session_list from render to show data

Comment: um, I don't think it will work like this. But, I have provided a solution which might help. Please see the update 2 section

Comment: it's alright i only need my codes to work, the render and redirect in same function should be another question on it own